# XSD / Maven: Duplicate entry

Tags: java, maven, binding, xsd, duplicates

I have the following problem:
I have a maven project where I compile some XSD.
In one of the XSD i have a duplicate. the element entry (`<xs:element name="VehicleRoot" minOccurs="0">`) appears two times.
I would like to bind only one of the entry but i cannot figure out how to do it.

I tried to bind it (see below), but how can i bind only the fist one or the second one ?

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"                                                                                                                                                                  
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          version="2.1">
    <bindings schemaLocation="TravelItineraryReadLLS2.2.0RS.xsd" version="1.0">
      <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Vehicle']">
                <class name="VehicleAttribute" />
      </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the XSD, create a type for that element, and reference that type when you declare the 2 elements instead.

Comment: I cannot change the XSD :)

Comment: Maybe try using : <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Vehicle'][1]">